# Less input by the user than asked

Tags: java, input

```
int[] arr=new int[4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Suppose i expected the user to provide 4 inputs but it gave only 3.
Expected= `1 2 3 4`
Given= `1 2 3`

**How do i avoid this error? please help**

````
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElement Exception

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor (Scanner.java:862)

at java.util.Scanner.next (Scanner.java: 1371) at Source.main(Source.java:16)```
````

Comment: As the scanner might be waiting for the final integer to be provided you might have to read the entire line and parse it yourself. That way you know what the user provided and don't have to wait for more.

Comment: how can i do it? i started java 3 days ago..would be really thankful if you helped <3

Comment: When you're that new to programming, usually you don't worry about input formatting and just require the input to always be correct.  If your instructor is requiring that you parse incorrectly formatted input after just three days, I think that is unreasonable.

Comment: I was attempting an assignment I got all the questions correct but got stuck at this one.
no google search was helpful.

Comment: what could a possible solution to this sir?

Comment: Have a look at `Scanner.nextLine()` to read the line, `String.split()` to split the line at spaces (read the JavaDocs on each of the methods to get the details) and `Integer.parseInt()` to parse each of the string parts to an `int`. Since you're meant to learn something and work on the task yourself I'll leave it at that, i.e. read up on those methods and try to put them together.

Comment: If you already manage to get the `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, then just catch and handle it. Read up on the `try{...} catch() { ...}` construct.

Comment: was on the same thing :p

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you put  sc.nextInt(); during runtime  JVM will ask for input
i see that you run you for loop four times hence jvm will ask for input four times
it will automatically cast you input to integer variable, if you put any other input it will throw error as
arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
you are storing jvm's user input in an integer array